# Returning the value of a slider from a web page to a program on change of slider

Tags: javascript, html, arduino, slider, esp32

I am trying to program a ESP32 to control the LED brightness using a slider and have been using some bits cobbled together from https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-servo-motor-web-server-arduino-ide/ and https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-pwm-arduino-ide/

So far I am able to get the ESP32 to connect to my network, display the slider and its value and, when the slider is changed, set the PWM to set the LED brightness.

The downside is that although I can get the slider value to be displayed in the browser while it is being changed the bit that gets me the value of the slider only runs when I release the mouse button. So instead of a slider controlling the LED in realtime I get a slider that sets the PWM value in jumps.

What I want to do is have the LED brightness represent the value on the slider as the slider is changed (before the mouse button is released).

I've tried with oninput and onchange but not had any luck. This isn't helped by my somewhat lacking skills in HTML.

Any pointers anyone could give me would be really appreciated.

My code is below:-

```
#include <WiFi.h>

/* Web server initialisation stuff */

/* Set the network credentials to connect to */

const char* ssid     = "MySID";
const char* password = "MySIDPassword";

/* Create a server instance on port 80 (http) */
WiFiServer server(80);

/* Create a variable to store the HTTP request */
String header;

/* Decode HTTP GET value */
String valueString = String(5);
int pos1 = 0;
int pos2 = 0;

/* LED initialisation stuff */
const byte led_pin = 2;
int intBbrightness = 0;

void setup() {
  /* Set the serial speed */
  Serial.begin(115200);

  /* Set up the LED Pin */
  ledcAttachPin (led_pin, 0);
  /* Set the initial PWM value, the frequency and the nummer of bits for resolution */
  ledcSetup(0,5000,8);

  /* Connect to Wi-Fi network with SSID and password */
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  /* Print local IP address and start web server */
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected.");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();   // Listen for incoming clients

  if (client) {                             // If a new client connects,
    Serial.println("New Client.");          // print a message out in the serial port
    String currentLine = "";                // make a String to hold incoming data from the client
    while (client.connected()) {            // loop while the client's connected
      if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,
        char c = client.read();             // read a byte, then
        Serial.write(c);                    // print it out the serial monitor
        header += c;
        if (c == '\n') {                    // if the byte is a newline character
          /* if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
          that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response: */
          if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
            /* HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
             and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a blank line: */
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-type:text/html");
            client.println("Connection: close");
            client.println();

            /* Display the HTML web page */
            client.println("<!DOCTYPE html><html>");
            client.println("<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">");
            client.println("<link rel=\"icon\" href=\"data:,\">");
            /* CSS to style the slider */
            client.println("<style>body { text-align: center; font-family: \"Trebuchet MS\", Arial; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}");
            client.println(".slider { width: 300px; }</style>");
            client.println("<script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js\"></script>");

            /* Web Page */
            /* Give the page a header here */
            client.println("</head><body><h1>ESP32 with Servo</h1>");

            /* Show the slider here */
            client.println("<p>Position: <span id=\"servoPos\"></span></p>");          
            client.println("<input type=\"range\" min=\"0\" max=\"256\" class=\"slider\" id=\"servoSlider\" onchange=\"servo(this.value)\" value=\""+valueString+"\"/>");

            /* Javascript for the slider */
            client.println("<script>var slider = document.getElementById(\"servoSlider\");");
            client.println("var servoP = document.getElementById(\"servoPos\"); servoP.innerHTML = slider.value;");
            client.println("slider.oninput = function() { slider.value = this.value; servoP.innerHTML = this.value; }");
            client.println("$.ajaxSetup({timeout:1000}); function servo(pos) { ");
            client.println("$.get(\"/?value=\" + pos + \"&\"); {Connection: close};}</script>");

            client.println("</body></html>");     

            /*GET /?value=180& HTTP/1.1 */
            if(header.indexOf("GET /?value=")>=0) {
              pos1 = header.indexOf('=');
              pos2 = header.indexOf('&');
              valueString = header.substring(pos1+1, pos2);

            /* Set the brightness of the LED based on the slider */
              ledcWrite(0,valueString.toInt());
              Serial.println(valueString); 
            }         
            /* The HTTP response ends with another blank line */
            client.println();
            /* Break out of the while loop */
            break;
          } else { // if you got a newline, then clear currentLine
            currentLine = "";
          }
        } else if (c != '\r') {  // if you got anything else but a carriage return character,
          currentLine += c;      // add it to the end of the currentLine
        }
      }
    }
    /* Clear the header variable */
    header = "";
    /* Close the connection */
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Client disconnected.");
    Serial.println("");
  }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want update the brightness on your code from a webpage, you have to use `onchange`.

This is the only way to update in "realtime".

I do not see your `updateBrightness` function in your code. You say, you can change it if you release the slider. But how, if there is no code to change it?

If you change the slider, you need to call the ESP with a new page. And to listen on this page, you have to add this to your setup code: `server.on("/slider", handleSliderChange);` for example.

Why will it not work even if you use `onchange()` ?
It will not work, because a HTML will generate 1000 requestes each second with the new value. Your ESP will never be able to handle so much requests.

What you have to do is to start ONLY 1 request to your ESP and wait, until the ESP answered. If, after the answer was received, the slider value changed, you can send the next value, until the slider value does not change anymore.

If, during the transmission of the new value, the slider calls `onchange`, you have just to save the new slider value, without send the request to the ESP.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. To your points above. 1. The update brightness part is not a function, it's the two lines of code below ```/* Set the brightness of the LED based on the slider */```. 2. Where does the ```server.on("/slider/"....``` code go? I'm guessing in the setup just after ```server.begin``` but I'm not sure. 3. From what you're describing in the last 2 paragraphs it sounds a lot like you're talking about getting the slider value after it stops changing, but I'm looking for the slider value as it's changing. Or am I just misreading that? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You can add "server.on" before begin. Since you add a callback function to the server (you can find a lot of examples also in the library folder). On the slider callback, you should be notified for each change, so `onchange` should be the right solution. It should be called like `onmousemove`, this means many times!

Comment: Hmm, tried that but it does not compile. Also looking at the WiFiServer class documentation there is no .on method, just Server(port).

Comment: WebServer - on the ESP32, you should use https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/WebServer to create a server.